# Unable to validate Dates in german using Datetime prompt validator

Tags: python-3.x, botframework

I have a DateResolverDialog which takes in date and returns a valid date if Date is recognized by datetime_prompt_validator.

It works well with default_locale but does not recognize dates entered in German. For e.g **23. Mai 2020**

```
class DateResolverDialog(CancelAndHelpDialog):
def __init__(self, dialog_id: str = None):
    super(DateResolverDialog, self).__init__(
        dialog_id or DateResolverDialog.__name__
    )

    self.add_dialog(
        DateTimePrompt(
            DateTimePrompt.__name__, DateResolverDialog.datetime_prompt_validator
        )
    )
    self.add_dialog(
        WaterfallDialog(
            WaterfallDialog.__name__ + "2", [self.initial_step, self.final_step]
        )
    )

    self.initial_dialog_id = WaterfallDialog.__name__ + "2"
    self.name = ""

async def initial_step(
    self, step_context: WaterfallStepContext
) -> DialogTurnResult:
    timex= None
    self.name = step_context.options



    prompt_msg_text = key.query_date_text.value if self.name is 'createtask' else key.query_appointment_date_text
    prompt_msg = MessageFactory.text(
    prompt_msg_text, prompt_msg_text, InputHints.expecting_input
    )

    reprompt_msg_text = key.date_format_text.value
    reprompt_msg = MessageFactory.text(
        reprompt_msg_text, reprompt_msg_text, InputHints.expecting_input
    )


    if timex is None:
        # We were not given any date at all so prompt the user.
        return await step_context.prompt(
            DateTimePrompt.__name__,
            PromptOptions(prompt=prompt_msg, retry_prompt=reprompt_msg),
        )
    if "definite" not in Timex(timex).types:
        # This is essentially a "reprompt" of the data we were given up front.
        return await step_context.prompt(
            DateTimePrompt.__name__, PromptOptions(prompt=reprompt_msg)
        )

    return await step_context.next(DateTimeResolution(timex=timex))

async def final_step(self, step_context: WaterfallStepContext):
    timex = step_context.result[0].timex
    print(timex)
    if (timex < str(date.today())):
        await step_context.context.send_activity(
            MessageFactory.text(key.date_error_text.value))
        return await step_context.replace_dialog(dialog_id=self.id,options = self.name)
    else:
        return await step_context.end_dialog(timex)

@staticmethod
async def datetime_prompt_validator(prompt_context: PromptValidatorContext) -> bool:
    if prompt_context.recognized.succeeded:
        print(prompt_context.recognized.value)
        timex = prompt_context.recognized.value[0].timex.split("T")[0]

        # TODO: Needs TimexProperty
        return "definite" in Timex(timex).types

    return False
```

Also, it appears there is no support for German culture as it gives error when trying to set **default_locale = Culture.German**

Language available for Culture are:
{Chinese,Dutch,English,French,Italian,Japanese,Korean,Portuguese,Spanish,Turkish}

I also tried using sample from Recognizers-Text [Recognizers-Text](https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/tree/master/Python/samples/simple_console). That too gives error on setting Culture parameter to German.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "recognizer.py", line 7, in <module>
DEFAULT_CULTURE = Culture.German
AttributeError: type object 'Culture' has no attribute 'German'.
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like German is not yet supported in Python: https://github.com/microsoft/Recognizers-Text/issues/1689

There's not a lot you can do in the meantime, but here are some ideas:

1. Write the bot in .NET
2. Use a LUIS recognizer

Comment: Thanks. I should probably try using LUIS datetimeV2 as it appears to give better results.

Comment: Dang it, why didn't I think of that?

Comment: For those using python, they can also try using dateparser library. Results are accurate. https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/